# Referencing - Harvard Australian Government Publishing Service Style and Abbreviations

Tags: graduate-school, citation-style, reference-managers

I'm working on my dissertation with the University of Sydney and need to use Harvard Australian Government Publishing Service (AGPS) referencing. I'm assuming that the below question will be applicable to all Harvard styles, but if anyone has specific advice in relation to AGPS that would be very much appreciated. The question specifically is in relation to abbreviations. I'm using Endnote for what it's worth.

*1) Several of my references are from international organisations such as The World Health Organisation (WHO), Food and Agriculture Organisation of the United Nations (FAO), and World Organisation for Animal Health (OIE).
For the in-text references, I'm hoping to use the abbreviation eg. (FAO, 2014) or (OIE, 2017) rather than every single time I use a reference from these organisations, to have to write out the full name e.g. (Food and Agriculture Organisation of the United Nations, 2014) or (World Organisation for Animal Health, 2017) - I've got a 10,000 word-limit, and writing this out every time could take up to 5% of my word count.
Would it be acceptable to use the abbreviation  under Harvard AGPS provided that the first time FAO is referenced, for example, I spell out the full name and provide the acronym, and then subsequently just use the abbreviation?*

*2) Also as a second question for anyone who may have used Harvard AGPS with University of Sydney - is the correct style to use in Endnote Harvard_UQ or harvard_usyd?  On the Library website - https://libguides.library.usyd.edu.au/c.php?g=508212&p=3476130 - they say to use Harvard_UQ, but I'm wondering if that page is out of date and there is an actual accepted Usyd Harvard Style.*